# $S=\{x\in X: \|x\|=1\}$ cannot be covered by a finite family of closed balls in X

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am working with an exercise and have som questions.
The exercise is

Let X be an infinite dimensional normed vector space  over $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$

Show that one cannot cover the unit sphere $S=\{x\in X: \|x\|=1\}$ with a finite family of closed balls in $X$ such that none of the balls contains 0.

I am thinking to show that S is not covered by a finite family of closed balls in X such that none of the balls contains 0. To show this I am thinking that I have to show $S\not\subset \cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$ and to show this I am thinking to take a $x\in S$ and show that $x \notin \cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$.

I note that for $x\in S$ I have that $\|x\|=1$. And to show that $x\notin \cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$ I am thinking that I have to show that $d(x,p)>r$ . And to show this I am thinking that I somehow have to use Riesz lemma, but to be able to use this lemma I have to have that $\cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$ is a closed proper subspace of X. It is obviously closed but I don't know how to show that it is a proper subspace of X.
But after I have argued that it is a proper subspace of X then I am thinking that I have from Riesz lemma that there exist a $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that $\|x-y\|\geq a$ for all $y\in 
\cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$, where $0<a<1$. Since we have that $p\in \cup \{x\in X| d(x,p)\leq r\}$ then we have that $\|x-p\| \geq a$, and what we want to show is that $d(x,p)>r$ i.e. $\|x-p\|>r$. So dont now how I get from $\|x-p\| \geq a$ to $\|x-p\|>r$

Answer (score 1):

I found another, easier proof using the Hahn-Banach theorem that works in the general case. Let $B_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ be closed balls not containing $0$. These balls are closed convex sets. Hence, we can find continous functionals $\lambda_i$, s.t. $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_i(x) \geq 1$ for $x \in B_i$. The vector space $V = \cap_{i=1}^n \mathrm{ker}(\lambda_i)$ does not intersect any of the $B_i$. But $V \neq 0$, because $X$ is infinite-dimensional. So we find an $x\in V \cap S$. Therefore, no finite number of closed balls not containing $0$ can cover $S$.

Comment: How do you know that these balls are closed convex sets?

Why does V not intersect any of the $B_i$

Comment: Any closed ball in a normed vector space is convex: $|| t x + (1-t) y - p || \leq t||x-p|| + (1-t) ||y-p|| \leq r$ for $x,y \in B(p,r), 0 \leq t \leq 1$. If $x \in V$, then $\lambda_i(x) = 0$ for all $i$. But $x \in B_i$ implies $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_i(x) \geq 1$.

Comment: It makes sense, but I am confused about how you use Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: I use a hyperplane separation theorem, which is a corollary to the usual Hahn-Banach theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#%22Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach%22_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems))). Remember that the closed balls $B_i$ have non-empty interior.

Comment: Note that the $\mathbb{R}$-linear function $l(tp) = -t ||p||, l: \mathbb{R}p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $l(tp) \leq ||tp||$ and can be extended to an $\mathbb{R}$-linear functional $\hat{l}$ on $X$ with $l(x) \leq ||x||$ for all $x\in X$. Setting $\rho(x) = \hat{l}(x) - \mathrm{i} \hat{l}( \mathrm{i} x)$ gives a $\mathbb{C}$-linear functional that satisfies $\mathrm{Re}\,\rho(x) \leq ||x||$ and by looking at $e^{i \alpha} x$ we conclude that $|\rho(x)| \leq ||x||$, i.e. that $\rho$ is continuous.

Comment: For $x \in B(p,r)$ we have then $\mathrm{Re}\,\rho(x) = \mathrm{Re}\,\rho(x-p) + \mathrm{Re}\,\rho(p) \leq r - ||p||$. Setting $\lambda = \rho / (r - ||p||)$ and noting that $r < ||p||$, we find that $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda(x) \geq 1$ for $x \in B(p,r)$.

Comment: You can imagine that the Hahn-Banach theorem gives you a hyper-plane that separates the closed ball from the origin. This is possible because a ball is convex and does not "touch" the origin. The parallel hyper-plane through the origin the has "one dimension less" than $X$ and is disjoint from the ball. Iterating this procedure gives a subspace of finite codimension in $X$ that is disjoint from the given finite set of closed balls. This is the space $V$.

Comment: Do you show that $\rho$ is continuous, so you can say that $\lambda$ is continuous? which you then will use to say that $\bigcap_{ i=1}^n ker(\lambda_i)\neq \{0\}$ and you show that $Re \lambda(x)\geq 1$, but in the answer you use that $Re\lambda_i(x)\geq 1$. I don't quite get how to combine these two? And what do you use to that $B_i$ is convex?

Comment: Of course, I can, because $\lambda = \rho/(r-||p||)$ it is just a $\rho$ rescaled. In the proof, I construct such a $\lambda$ for each of the balls $B_i$. In the construction I use the convexity of $B_i$ implicitly in the seminorm $||.||$. I only mentioned convexity in the answer, because this is how the hyper-plane separation theorem (a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem) works. The point of the proof is that given a finite number of closed balls, $B_1, B_2, \ldots B_n$ not containing the origin, I can construct a $\lambda_i$ for each of them.

Comment: These $\lambda_i$ have the property that for every $i$ it holds true, that $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_i(x) \geq 1$, whenever $x \in B_i$. But, if $x \in V$, then $\lambda_i(x) = 0$, so $x \notin \cup_{i=1}^n B_i$. But if $V\neq 0$, we can find a vector $x \in V$ with $x \neq 0$, however $x/||x|| \in S$ but $x \notin \cup_{i=1}^n B_i$. In order to show $V \neq 0$, one could argue that if it were true that $V = 0$, then the map $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n, x \mapsto (\lambda_i(x))$ is injective. This is only possible if $\mathrm{dim}(X) \neq n$, but $X$ is infinite dimensional, so $V \neq 0$. Q.E.D.

Comment: @Sumi: The continuity of $\lambda_i$ is not used.

Answer (score 0):

In the union $\cup\{x \in X, d(x,p) \leq r \}$, what are the values of $p$? I assume that $p$ and $r$ run over a finite set. Let me denote the closed ball around $p$ with radius $r$ by $B(p,r) = \{x \in X, d(x,p) \leq r \}$ and assume by contradiction that $S \subset \cup_{i=1}^n B(p_i,r_i)$. Since the balls are centered on $S$ and cannot contain $0$, we have $||p_i|| = 1$ and $0 < r_i < 1$.

Now, let $e_1$ be a unit vector. Then, $e_1 \in B(p_{i_1},r_{i_1})$ for some $1 \leq i_1  \leq n$. Riesz's lemma now finds an $e_2 \in S$, s.t. for $y \in lin\{e_1,p_{i_1}\} = W_1$ we have $||y-e_2|| \geq r_{i_1}$. In particular, $e_2 \notin B(p_{i_1},r_{i_1})$.
Iterating this construction, we find closed subspaces $W_k = lin\{e_1,p_{i_1},\ldots,e_k,p_{i_k}\}$, $e_{k+1} \notin W_k \cup \cup_{j=1}^k B(p_{i_j},r_{i_j})$ and $i_r \neq i_s$ for $r \neq s$. Since $X$ is infinite dimensional, $W_k$ are always proper subspaces of $X$. But then we obtain a contraction when $k=n$.

Comment: I don't think you can assume $\lVert p_i\rVert=1$, but that could be easily worked around.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you are doing? Is it possible that you can explain it in another way?

Comment: @Sumi I am assuming by contradiction that $S$ can be covered by finitely many closed balls not containing $0$ and show that this is impossible if $X$ is infinite dimensional. As user10354138 pointed out, my proof works only if the centres of the balls in the cover are in $S$ and has to be fixed otherwise.

Comment: @Sumi The case that $||p_i|| = 1$ can be proven more easily: $W = lin\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ and choose $x \in S$, s.t. $||x - w|| \geq max\{r_1,\ldots, r_n\}$ for all $w \in W$. Then, $x \notin B(p_i,r_i)$ for all $i$.

Comment: Just to see that if I understand it correctly so you show the second paragraph in you first answer, to show that $W_{k}$ is a proper subspace?

Comment: $W_k$ is always finite dimensional by construction, and so proper, because $X$ is infinite dimensional. It has to be proper to be able to apply the Riesz lemma. Remember that finite dimensional subspaces are always closed.